# Meteor - Create slug in Meteor.users

Tags: javascript, meteor, slug

I have created a simple user using "accounts-password" package. Here is my code:

```
Template.register.events({
    'submit form': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $('[name=email]').val();
        var password = $('[name=password]').val();
        Accounts.createUser({
            email: email,
            password: password
        }, function(error){
            if(error){
                console.log(error.reason);
            }
            else{
                Router.go("home");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now I have a users collection, and I would like to add a slug property so I can use it in my routes. Reading documentation, I guess I need to add the slug in the user's "profile" field right?

I was trying to use todda00:friendly-slugs package to create the slug, but I don't know how to use it with Meteor.users.update. Can someone help me on that?

Comment: what field are you gonna make the slug from? email probably is not the good one

Comment: Let's say there is a name field in Profile. I will make the slug from there. Now how I do it ?